# Using multiprocessing on a function fails with - string indices must be integers

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a function, that works in a single thread. Here's a simplified example. Basically I'm wanting to verify a few dead links and store the result in each item in a list of dictionaries.

```
import requests
import sys
import logging

def main():  
    urls_to_check = [{'url': 'http://example.com'},
                     {'url': 'http://example.com'},
                     {'url': 'http://example.com'}]
    print check_for_404(urls_to_check)

def check_for_404(urls_to_check):
    for item in urls_to_check:
        r = requests.get(item['url'])
        item.update({'responseCode': r.status_code})
    return urls_to_check

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        main()
    except:
        logging.error("Unexpected error:" + str(sys.exc_info()))
```

Outputs:

```
[{'url': 'http://example.com', 'responseCode': 200}, {'url': 'http://example.com', 'responseCode': 200}, {'url': 'http://example.com', 'responseCode': 200}]
```

And I'm happy with that

Now if I implement multiprocessing, which I understand is to split up an iterable across multiple cores and run parts of the iterable through the function...

```
import requests
import sys
import logging
from multiprocessing import Pool

def main():  
    urls_to_check = [{'url': 'http://example.com'},
                     {'url': 'http://example.com'},
                     {'url': 'http://example.com'}]
    p = Pool(5)
    print p.map(check_for_404, urls_to_check)

def check_for_404(urls_to_check):
    for item in urls_to_check:
        r = requests.get(item['url'])
        item.update({'responseCode': r.status_code})
    return urls_to_check

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        main()
    except:
        logging.error("Unexpected error:" + str(sys.exc_info()))
```

I get the error `TypeError('string indices must be integers, not str',), <traceback object at 0x10ad6c128>)`

How can I implement multiprocessing so that I can process a long list of urls more quickly?

This is the tutorial I'm looking at:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html

Comment: Please show the complete error message and full traceback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change your "check for 404's" function to accept a single url rather than a list; the map function passes the list elements in one at a time (to separate subprocesses in the pool), then reassembles them back into a list at the end:

```
def check_for_404(item):
    r = requests.get(item['url'])
    item.update({'responseCode': r.status_code})
    return item
```

Comment: Can the function take other parameters when being called by the multiprocessor? e.g. `def check_for_404(item, some_other_string_i_may_want_to_use):`

Comment: i think the easiest way would be to include all your parameters in the dict, eg. `{'url':'example.com', 'other_string':'blabla'}`, and have your function pull them out

Comment: Ah yes I thought that could be an idea too. Thanks again.

Comment: Hmm, since the iteration happens out side the function (which as discussed is set up for a single item). So unpacking a dictionary inside the function isn't going to work.

Comment: what do you mean? the dictionary gets passed to the function, that's what `item` is.

Comment: Yeah I got it to work thanks. I'm sending a list of dictionaries containing just a key and value in each. It's overkill but I really need to preserve a parameter through the multiprocessor function.

Comment: cool, i don't think it's overkill at all, a dict/json is the usual data structure for "message passing"/queuing algorithms like this